# How to inflate the dropdown from the multidimentional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to loop through an array for inflate the dropdown. But I am not able to do so. I have tried many methods for this. But Nothing works for me. One of the method I try below

Here is the array which I am trying to inflate in dropdown. There are 22 array in this single array which I am trying to inflate.

```
 array(22) {
     [0] => array(4) {
         [0] => string(26) "Black Angled Buckle Jacket"
         [1] => string(6) "036890"
         [2] => int(48503) 
         [3] => array(4) {
             [0] => string(83) "http://thebestofcards.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/product-man-6a-uai-480x640.jpg"
             [1] => int(480) 
             [2] => int(640) 
             [3] => bool(false)
         }
     }
     ...
 }
```

This is the code

```
$result = count($data);

var_dump($data);
for ($row = 0; $row < $result; $row++) {
    //echo "<p><b>Row number $row</b></p>";
    echo '<select name="productddl">';
    //echo "<ul>";
    for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++) {
        echo '<option value="'.$data[$row][$col][0].'">'.$data[$row][$col][1].'</option>'
        //echo "<li>".$data[$row][$col]."</li>";
    }
    echo '</select>';;
    //echo "</ul>";
}
```

I just want to fetch the product name in the array to the dropdown. Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: The structure of that array is horrible. Where does the data come from? What exactly are you trying to do? Add the titles to the dropdown?

Comment: its comming from the wocommerce products. I write code to fetch the woocommerce products list in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

that's not so difficult, array isn't too nested, it is just a list of products, the only issue is that instead of using assoc and more meaningful keys, you have numbers.

```
echo '<select name="productddl">';
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo '<option value="', $row[1], '">', $row[0] , '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```