# How to fetch all the woocommerce products from the database using php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to fetch all the products of the woocommerce from the database using php.. But it is not giving me the list of all products

```
  <select Name='choose'>
  <?php
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product' ,'posts_per_page' => 100);
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
      $loop->the_post();
      echo '<option selected value="'.the_title().'</option>';
  endwhile;
  ?>
</select>
```

can anybody please tell me how can I get all the products of woo commerce

Thanks

Comment: where is `product_cat` ?

Comment: I want all category products

Comment: try to get one category first, then get a all category names in `array` format and pass it

Comment: also see this .. http://www.functionsphp.com/get-list-of-all-woocommerce-products/

Comment: I already try this but it is not working for me @LifeTimeProgrammer.. check out I also ask question regarding this thats why I move to this method  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020190/how-to-inflate-the-dropdown-from-the-multidimentional-array-in-php

Comment: sry bro some one help to you , :(

Comment: that thing is not working

Comment: @azad chouhan. I have provided with the solution over here. Have a try and let me know if you face any hindrance.

Comment: @azad chouhan. Have you obtained the solution as per the method that i have suggested. Share thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

> In order to **fetch Single product** to your single.php page you can make use of the code which i have already suggested over here. Refer here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240653/how-to-query-single-product-in-woocommerce/240726#240726

> In order to **fetch All products** that you have into your DB you can follow the steps below.

You can fetch the Woo-commerce Products based on the `WP_Query` also so that it is also saved in the `wp_posts` table alone. So that we might slightly modify the post type alone for getting the `WP_Query` to work on.

**Step One:**
First We shall see to the parameters what we have to pass for the WP_Query.

```
$params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5, 
        'post_type' => 'product'
);
```

**Note:**  As you can see, all we’ve done is added a post_type variable to the array, and set it’s value to "product"; the query will now look for WooCommerce products instead of posts.

**Step Two:** After that we have to run on with the same structure that the Normal WP_Query behaves.

```
<?php
$params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5, 
        'post_type' => 'product'
);
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params); 
?>
<?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) :  ?>
<?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : $wc_query->the_post();  ?>
<?php the_title(); //Prints the title over Here ?>
<?php //You can add what ever you need from the loop over here ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
<p>
     <?php _e( 'No Products' );  ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

### Explanations

- An array of parameters for WP_Query to work with is created; to start with it’s just the basic posts, but by adding more specifics to these parameters we can achieve different results for our queries.
- `WP_Query` is used to query the parameters created in the first line.
- The query is checked to see if it returned any results.
- If there are results, then we iterate over them:

  - First, setting the global variable `$post`, which ensures that the next function works.
  - Second, setting the `the_title()` variable, which is responsible for displaying the product title.
- Then, when the posts are displayed, we return the $post variable to its original state with the`wp_reset_postdata` function.

Using this [link](https://www.gavick.com/blog/wp_query-woocommerce-products) i have studied how to query the WooCommerce Products using WP_Query and I have shared here so that all might get used with this posts.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine on my machine, However its seems some conflict to your previous wp query. You can also try to get all product like this..

```
<select Name='choose'>
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product' ,'posts_per_page' => 100);
$products = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $products as $product ) : 
  echo '<option selected value="'.$product->post_title.'</option>';
endforeach;
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('vm_posts');
        $this->db->join('vm_postmeta', 'vm_postmeta.post_id = vm_posts.id');
        $this->db->join('vm_wc_product_meta_lookup', 'vm_wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id = vm_postmeta.post_id');
        $this->db->join('vm_inventory', 'vm_wc_product_meta_lookup.sku = vm_inventory.product_sku');
        $this->db->join('vm_terms', 'vm_inventory.customer_id = vm_terms.name');
        $this->db->where('post_type','product');
        $query = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.